# Background-color and spacing between posts in posting system

Tags: html, css

Now, I have a posting system. There's an input field and a submit button. After entering something in the field and clicking the button, it gets displayed as a post.

Now, let's say you make multiple posts (two or three), all of them should be the same (except for the body of the post). However, the issue I'm encountering is that the first post has a background-color of Silver (#C0C0C0), but the second or third posts don't. However, the body, and other content in the post such as the like and comment buttons are there.

To fix this, I inspected the first post and it highlighted only the first post, not the second or third posts, when I hovered over the post div in the console. The posts should have a background color of silver, and if you have multiple posts, there should be some white space in between the posts. But if I increase the height of the background-color, it covers both the first and second post, without any white space. And when I did this (increased the height of the background-color) of the post and inspected the second post, it highlighted both the first and second post as , without any white space in between the two posts. I want there to be if, someone enters more than one post, the posts should have white space between them, and it should be like there's multiple separate posts, and all the posts have a background-color of #C0C0C0 (Silver). Also, the posts should have a border-radius of 5px. How can I accomplish this? Please help.

Code:

```
<div class="textPost">
  <?php

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  ?>
  <div class="textpostFormat">
    <-- All the post content (body, like button, comment button, etc.) -->
  </div>
  <?php

  }
}

  ?>
</div>

<style media="screen">
   
.textPost {
  margin-top: 170px;
  width: 650px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 685px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.textpostFormat {
  margin-left: -640px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

I tried this CSS code:

```
<style media="screen">

.textPost {
  margin-top: 170px;
  width: 650px;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 685px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.textpostFormat {
  margin-left: -640px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

</style>
```

But, it gives neither the first or second post a background-color at all.

Comment: You shouldn't be using position: fixed for this. All your posts will be overlapping each other.

Comment: can you share your code on online editors?

Comment: @dantheman Tried removing it. They overlapped after removing it.

Comment: @M.RMRF But I shared all the necessary code over here.